# Problem with converting chemdraw files into eps files removes original fonts and style (bold, italic)

Tags: fonts, eps

I have a serious problem, which makes LaTeX unusable right now for me. I reinstalled MiKTeX (build 2.9.7206) and Texmaker (build 5.0.4) on Windows. When I am trying to include an `.eps` file which was generated via the chemdraw software (build 15.1), the original font from the chemdraw document (e.g Arial) is changed to the LaTeX font style. Furthermore, if I want to make the number bold, the number completely disappears in the created `.pdf` file. It seems like LaTeX does not recognize the font of the chemdraw generated `.eps` file and though replaces it. The problem did not occur with older versions of MiKTeX or Texmaker back in 2017. Attached you find the chemdraw file (https://workupload.com/file/K9A3b5Bn) and the same file saved as an eps file (https://workupload.com/file/4REEBTWh).

UPDATE: I solved the problem by installing full miktex installation via the net installer!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,captions=nooneline,twoside]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{test.eps}

\end{document}
```

Log file after compiling:

````
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.2.4) 5 FEB 2020 10:58
entering extended mode
**./test.tex
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02>
L3 programming layer <2020-01-31>
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrar
tcl.cls"
Document Class: scrartcl 2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script document class (article)
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrkb
ase.sty"
Package: scrkbase 2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent b
asics and keyval usage)
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrba
se.sty"
Package: scrbase 2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent
basics and keyval usage)
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.s
ty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrlf
ile.sty"
Package: scrlfile 2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
)))
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\tocba
sic.sty"
Package: tocbasic 2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip47
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box45
)
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `toc'
(tocbasic) because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic) for `toc' on input line 137.
Package scrartcl Info: You've used standard option `12pt'.
(scrartcl) This is correct!
(scrartcl) Internally I'm using `fontsize=12pt'.
(scrartcl) If you'd like to set the option with \KOMAoptions,
(scrartcl) you'd have to use `fontsize=12pt' there
(scrartcl) instead of `12pt', too.
Class scrartcl Info: File `scrsize12pt.clo' used to setup font sizes on input l
ine 2212.
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrsi
ze12pt.clo"
File: scrsize12pt.clo 2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script font size class option (12pt
)
)
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\typea
rea.sty"
Package: typearea 2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script package (type area)
\ta@bcor=\skip48
\ta@div=\count167
Package typearea Info: You've used standard option `a4paper'.
(typearea) This is correct!
(typearea) Internally I'm using `paper=a4'.
(typearea) If you'd like to set the option with \KOMAoptions,
(typearea) you'd have to use `paper=a4' there
(typearea) instead of `a4paper', too.
\ta@hblk=\skip49
\ta@vblk=\skip50
\ta@temp=\skip51
\footheight=\skip52
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea) DIV = 12
(typearea) BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea) \paperwidth = 597.50793pt
(typearea) \textwidth = 448.13095pt
(typearea) DIV departure = -6%
(typearea) \evensidemargin = 27.31467pt
(typearea) \oddsidemargin = -22.47766pt
(typearea) \paperheight = 845.04694pt
(typearea) \textheight = 635.5pt
(typearea) \topmargin = -41.72441pt
(typearea) \headheight = 18.125pt
(typearea) \headsep = 21.75pt
(typearea) \topskip = 12.0pt
(typearea) \footskip = 50.75pt
(typearea) \baselineskip = 14.5pt
(typearea) on input line 1719.
)
\c@part=\count168
\c@section=\count169
\c@subsection=\count170
\c@subsubsection=\count171
\c@paragraph=\count172
\c@subparagraph=\count173
\scr@dte@section@maxnumwidth=\skip53
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl) for `\section on input line 4723.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl) for `\section on input line 4723.
\scr@dte@part@maxnumwidth=\skip54
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=false'
(scrartcl) for `\part on input line 4731.
\scr@dte@subsection@maxnumwidth=\skip55
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl) for `\subsection on input line 4741.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl) for `\subsection on input line 4741.
\scr@dte@subsubsection@maxnumwidth=\skip56
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl) for `\subsubsection on input line 4751.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl) for `\subsubsection on input line 4751.
\scr@dte@paragraph@maxnumwidth=\skip57
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl) for `\paragraph on input line 4761.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl) for `\paragraph on input line 4761.
\scr@dte@subparagraph@maxnumwidth=\skip58
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl) for `\subparagraph on input line 4771.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl) for `\subparagraph on input line 4771.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip59
\belowcaptionskip=\skip60
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box46
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lof'
(tocbasic) because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic) for `lof' on input line 6002.
\scr@dte@figure@maxnumwidth=\skip61
\c@figure=\count174
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lot'
(tocbasic) because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic) for `lot' on input line 6014.
\scr@dte@table@maxnumwidth=\skip62
\c@table=\count175
Class scrartcl Info: Redefining `\numberline' on input line 6178.
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\babel.sty
"
Package: babel 2020/01/15 3.38 The Babel package
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\switch.de
f"
File: switch.def 2020/01/15 3.38 Babel switching mechanism
)
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/arabi\bblopts.cfg
"
File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of
babel
)
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-german\nger
man.ldf"
Language: ngerman 2018/12/08 v2.11 German support for babel (post-1996 orthogra
phy)
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-german\nger
manb.ldf"
Language: ngermanb 2018/12/08 v2.11 German support for babel (post-1996 orthogr
aphy)
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\babel.def
"
File: babel.def 2020/01/15 3.38 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count176
\U@D=\dimen135
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\txtbabel.
def")
\bbl@readstream=\read2
\bbl@dirlevel=\count177
)
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 121.
)))
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/lm\lmodern.sty"
Package: lmodern 2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font) OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/lmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font) OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/lmm/m/it on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font) OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/lmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font) OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font) OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/lmm/b/it on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font) OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/lmsy/b/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font) OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font) OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font) OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/lmss/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font) OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/lmr/m/it on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font) OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/lmss/bx/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/lmr/bx/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 38.
)
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx
.sty"
Package: graphicx 2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics
.sty"
Package: graphics 2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\grap
hics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 105.
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdft
ex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen136
\Gin@req@width=\dimen137
)
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backe
nd-pdfmode.def"
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2019-04-06 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count178
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box47
) (test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info: Trying to load font information for OT1+lmr on input line 6
.
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/lm\ot1lmr.fd"
File: ot1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-
pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count179
\scratchdimen=\dimen138
\scratchbox=\box48
\nofMPsegments=\count180
\nofMParguments=\count181
\everyMPshowfont=\toks15
\MPscratchCnt=\count182
\MPscratchDim=\dimen139
\MPnumerator=\count183
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count184
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks16
)
("C:\Users\MJK\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epst
opdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.
)
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <test.eps>
(epstopdf) date: 2020-02-05 10:56:25
(epstopdf) size: 14883 bytes
(epstopdf) Output file: <test-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf) date: 2020-02-05 10:56:54
(epstopdf) size: 4027 bytes
(epstopdf) Command: <epstopdf --outfile=test-eps-converted-to.pdf t
est.eps>
(epstopdf) \includegraphics on input line 8.
Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file ./test-eps-converted-to.pdf): PDF inclusion: fou
nd PDF version <1.7>, but at most version <1.5> allowed
<test-eps-converted-to.pdf, id=1, 56.21pt x 61.22874pt>
File: test-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use test-eps-converted-to.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: test-eps-converted-to.pdf used on input line 8.
(pdftex.def) Requested size: 56.20985pt x 61.22858pt.
[1
{C:/Users/MJK/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map} <./test-eps
-converted-to.pdf>] (test.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
4349 strings out of 481570
85391 string characters out of 2913824
436482 words of memory out of 3000000
19583 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
535584 words of font info for 26 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
45i,6n,56p,10128b,246s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
{C:/Users/MJK/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX
2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-rm.enc}<C:/Users/MJK/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX
2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr12.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 17839 bytes).
PDF statistics:
17 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
6 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)```
````

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!

Comment: Your example works without problem for me. Can you post the log file you get?

Comment: How are you compiling?

Comment: Im compiling with Texmaker and the command PDFLaTeX @UlrikeFischer

Comment: @RalfStubner added the log (see above)

Comment: put the `test-eps-converted-to.pdf` somewhere for download.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Please find attached the test-eps-converted-to.pdf file: https://workupload.com/file/MxwmDnNZ

Comment: As Ralf says there is clearly some ghostscript problem. I can't reproduce it on my system. Do you have an external ghostscript? Do you have a full miktex installation? Do you have adobe reader installed?

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your help.@UlrikeFischer Tbh I dont even know what ghostscript does in particular. To the best of my knowledge, I dont think I am using any external ghostscript. I have a basic miktex installation and I am using Adobe Acrobat Reader DC. I also installed the basic miktex installer and texmaker on a different machine, also reinstalled a couple of times. Still the same problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I now installed the full miktex installation via the net installer. Deleted the old eps-converted-to.pdf file and compiled again. Its now working.....Must be something wrong with the basic installation. Thank you very much for the hint and help!

Answer (score 1):

The GhostScript installation on your system is incorrectly configured. Your `test.eps` clearly states that Helvetica should be used but is not included:

```
%%DocumentFonts: Helvetica
```

The `test-eps-converted-fto.pdf` still claims that Helvetica is used:

```
pdffonts test-eps-converted-to.pdf 
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
IROFMT+Helvetica                     Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no       8  0
```

However, if one converts the (binary) PDF back to (ascii) PostScript using `pdftops` one finds:

```
%%BeginResource: font IROFMT+Helvetica
%!FontType1-1.0: IROFMT+Helvetica
12 dict begin
/FontInfo 10 dict dup begin
/Notice (\(URW\)++,Copyright 1999 by \(URW\)++ Design & Development. See\
 the file COPYING \(GNU General Public License\) for license con\
ditions. As a special exception, permission is granted to includ\
e this font program in a Postscript or PDF file that consists of\
 a doc) readonly def
/Copyright (Copyright \(URW\)++,Copyright 1999 by \(URW\)++ Design & Develo\
pment) readonly def
/FullName (Nimbus Mono L Regular) readonly def
/FamilyName (Nimbus Mono L) readonly def
```

Somehow your GhostScript did not know about Helvetica and substituted it with the Courier clone that ships with GhostScript. Instead of Nimbus Mono L, the Helvetica clone Nimbus Sans L should have been used.

Unfortunately I do not know enough about GhostScript on Windows to offer a way to fix this issue.